# MBProgressHUD is displayed only when the operation is finished

Tags: ios, xcode, mbprogresshud

i'm using MBProgressHUD to show a popup with a loading animation but i have a problem. The progress indicator call is executed when i press a button. This is the action

```
- (IBAction)calendarioButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
hud.labelText = @"Uploading";
[hud show:YES];
[self getCalendarioJson];
}
```

in the getCalendarioJson i have this

```
- (void) getCalendarioJson {

//LETTURA CALENDARIO - INIZIO
NSString *calLink = myLink;

NSData* responseData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:calLink]];


NSArray* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                 JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1
                 options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSDictionary *firstObject = [json objectAtIndex:0];

NSDictionary *cal = [firstObject objectForKey:@"output"];
variabiliGlobali.calendario = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *dict in cal) {
    [variabiliGlobali.calendario addObject: dict];
}

//LETTURA CALENDARIO - FINE

}
```

Why does the loading popup appear only at the end of getCalendarioJson execution?
The button have a segue. When i go back from the target view i can see the popup.

What is the metter? If i delete the segue i can see the popup at the end of getCalendarioJson execution (because there is not a segue).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you set progress for that bar?

Comment: The colored part of the bar (i.e. 50%) responds to the 'progress' value you send to the Bar. So if you sets progressBar.progress = 0.5, the progressBar will be coloured on 50%. I've put an answer with code.

Answer (score 0):

You have a method `[self getCalendarioJson];` but this method run in the main thread, the main thread is for UI updates, when you download data or make a operation with several seconds of duration, the main thread wait for make the UI update.

For solve this situation, put the method in a background thread, can you use `[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(getCalendarioJson) withObject:nil];`

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

```
MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeAnnularDeterminate;
hud.labelText = @"Loading";
[self doSomethingInBackgroundWithProgressCallback:^(float progress) {
    hud.progress = progress; //Here you set the progress
} completionCallback:^{
    [hud hide:YES];
}];
```

You should set the progress value.